# Node.JS build broken on Azure DevOps with Windows image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops&tabs=code) for Node.js user can use either Windows or Linux agents to run builds. I have React.JS app which builds just fine with 'linux-latest' (Ubuntu 18.04), but fails to build on 'windows-latest' which is weird because on local Windows machine it builds just fine. What do I miss here?

Here is pipeline (1st part Node.JS 2nd Java/Spring/Maven):

```
trigger:
  - testing

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '10.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: |
      npm install
      npm run build:testing
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/myapp-react'
    displayName: 'npm install and build for test environment'

  #- task: CopyFiles@2
  #  inputs:
  #    Contents:
  #      myapp-react/build/**
  #    TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

  # Archive files
  # Compress files into .7z, .tar.gz, or .zip
  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: myapp-react/build/
      #includeRootFolder: true
      archiveType: 'zip' # Options: zip, 7z, tar, wim
      #tarCompression: 'gz' # Optional. Options: gz, bz2, xz, none
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
      replaceExistingArchive: true
      verbose: # Optional
      #quiet: # Optional

  - task: Maven@3
    inputs:
      mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
      mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
      javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
      jdkVersionOption: '1.11'
      jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
      publishJUnitResults: true
      testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
      goals: 'package'

  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      Contents:
        myapp/target/*.jar
      TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
      ArtifactName: MyWebApp
      publishLocation: 'Container' # Options: container, filePath
      #targetPath: # Required when publishLocation == FilePath
      #parallel: false # Optional
      #parallelCount: # Optional
      #fileCopyOptions: #Optional
```

Here is log from 'npm install' which shows no errors so build moves to the next step.

```
> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall D:\a\1\s\synesupp-react\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: 
> https://opencollective.com/core-js 
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock 

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@3.8.3 postinstall D:\a\1\s\synesupp-react\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.8.3 postinstall D:\a\1\s\synesupp-react\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.1 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

added 1701 packages from 1005 contributors and audited 1707 packages in 124.426s

87 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 2 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
Finishing: npm install and build for test environment
```

Output from 'archive' step shows there is no output folder hence no archive can be created.

```
2021-01-29T17:37:00.5462168Z ##[section]Starting: ArchiveFiles
2021-01-29T17:37:00.5594055Z ==============================================================================
2021-01-29T17:37:00.5594493Z Task         : Archive files
2021-01-29T17:37:00.5594748Z Description  : Compress files into .7z, .tar.gz, or .zip
2021-01-29T17:37:00.5594982Z Version      : 2.179.0
2021-01-29T17:37:00.5595183Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-01-29T17:37:00.5595500Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files
2021-01-29T17:37:00.5595834Z ==============================================================================
2021-01-29T17:37:00.7712175Z Found 1 files
2021-01-29T17:37:00.7714319Z Archiving file: build
2021-01-29T17:37:00.7784904Z [command]D:\a\_tasks\ArchiveFiles_d8b84976-e99a-4b86-b885-4849694435b0\2.179.0\7zip\7z.exe a -tzip -mx=5 D:\a\1\a\6516.zip @D:\a\_temp\7v7fy5rr8dw
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8011450Z 
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8011732Z 
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8012696Z WARNING: The system cannot find the file specified.
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8013336Z 7-Zip [64] 16.00 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-10
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8013951Z build
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8014056Z 
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8014312Z 
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8014581Z Scanning the drive:
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8015066Z 0 files, 0 bytes
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8015298Z 
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8015692Z Creating archive: D:\a\1\a\6516.zip
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8015994Z 
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8016365Z Items to compress: 0
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8016608Z 
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8016834Z 
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8017211Z Files read from disk: 0
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8017635Z Archive size: 22 bytes (1 KiB)
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8017914Z 
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8018312Z Scan WARNINGS for files and folders:
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8018586Z 
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8019012Z build : The system cannot find the file specified.
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8019442Z ----------------
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8019845Z Scan WARNINGS: 1
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8058812Z ##[error]Error: Archive creation failed for archive file: D:\a\1\a\6516.zip 
code: 1 
stdout: 
7-Zip [64] 16.00 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-10

Scanning the drive:
0 files, 0 bytes

Creating archive: D:\a\1\a\6516.zip

Items to compress: 0


Files read from disk: 0
Archive size: 22 bytes (1 KiB)

Scan WARNINGS for files and folders:

build : The system cannot find the file specified.
----------------
Scan WARNINGS: 1
 
stderr: 
WARNING: The system cannot find the file specified.
build

 
error: undefined;
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8076687Z ##[error]Archive creation failed for archive file: D:\a\1\a\6516.zip 
code: 1 
stdout: 
7-Zip [64] 16.00 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-10

Scanning the drive:
0 files, 0 bytes

Creating archive: D:\a\1\a\6516.zip

Items to compress: 0


Files read from disk: 0
Archive size: 22 bytes (1 KiB)

Scan WARNINGS for files and folders:

build : The system cannot find the file specified.
----------------
Scan WARNINGS: 1
 
stderr: 
WARNING: The system cannot find the file specified.
build

 
error: undefined;
2021-01-29T17:37:00.8101833Z ##[section]Finishing: ArchiveFiles
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually this is how I've solved it, although I don't know why this works and if this is really the best way to solve it:

I've split

```
steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '10.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: |
      npm install
      npm run build:testing
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/myapp-react'
    displayName: 'npm install and build for test environment'
```

into

```
steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '12.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

  - script: npm install
    displayName: 'Install dependencies'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/synesupp-react'

  - script: npm run build:testing
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/synesupp-react'
    displayName: 'Build project'
```